# Getting an error with routes [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, routes, match

I am going through Michael's Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial and I am getting an error in the routes.rb.

This is my code in routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'
  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
 You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (ArgumentError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"
```

I am confused. Should I use get "controller#action" or match? And what is the proper code when using match?

Comment: As error states and [docs explain](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) you'd need another parameter for http verb(s).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use `get` or specify `match '/signup', :to => 'users#new', via: :get`. Basically that's what error says.

You can check the docs: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)

Comment: Thank you it worked. I was using via: [:get] which was also giving me an error

Comment: You can use either variants `via: :get` or `via: [:get]`